# Ternary Logic php issue

Tags: php, syntax, ternary

The var $bt_ent contain the letter 'V' or 'L', so why the visibility of my td stay empty? My Ternary Logic isn't good ?

My code :

```
<?php $bt_ent = $this->depotInformation->bt_entite->getValue() ?>
<td style="visibility : <?php $bt_ent = 'V' ? 'visible' : 'hidden'; ?>">
    <div id="poidUnitaire" style="margin:0px 100px 0px 0px;" >
```

The DevTools :

```
<td style="visibility : ">
    <div id="poidUnitaire" style="margin:0px 100px 0px 0px;">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning ( `=` ) instead of comparing ( `==` ). Also an `echo` is missing to actually output the result.

```
<?php $bt_ent = $this->depotInformation->bt_entite->getValue() ?>
<td style="visibility : <?php echo $bt_ent == 'V' ? 'visible' : 'hidden'; ?>">
    <div id="poidUnitaire" style="margin:0px 100px 0px 0px;" >
```

Comment: So if you want to print the resolut of a ternary logic you have to put an echo before the condition?  Alright thank you a lot!

Comment: Everything you want from PHP to be in your final HTML-Code must be printed out in any way.

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning `$bt_ent` instead of printing it.

change

```
<?php $bt_ent = 'V' ? 'visible' : 'hidden'; ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo ($bt_ent == 'V' ? 'visible' : 'hidden'); ?>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what `echo 'V' ? 'visible' : 'hidden';` is meant to do.